# Finding the shortest path in a grid which has walls

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

The problem is that you want to travel from the top left corner of a grid to the bottom right corner (You are initially at the top left corner). Now, there are some walls in some cells, and you have a magic wand which you can use $k$ times to destroy a wall. How do we find the shortest path from the top left corner to the bottom right?

Comment: **Please add a reference to the original question.** Always. Always. Always. (If it does not make sense, do tell people why. For example, the source is behind a paywall. Even in that case, mention that paywall and its location, since some people might have access to it.)

Comment: Would you be happy with an algorithm having a time complexity of $O(kn)$?

Comment: @Steven Yes, sure.

Comment: Nice exercise!  However, we discourage posts that are the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it for you.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $w$ be the width of the grid and $h$ be its height. Let $n = w \cdot h$.
The following solution requires $O(n k)$ time and works regardless of whether there are restrictions on the direction of movement. If the movement is allowed only downwards and rightwards then there is a solution with a running time of $O(n)$, which is better whenever $k$ is not a constant (see Nir Shahar's answer).

Assume that there is no wall on the upper-left cell (otherwise remove it, and decrease $k$ by $1$).

Construct a directed graph $G$ as follows: the vertex set $V=\{1,\dots,h\} \times \{1, \dots, w\}$ consists of $n$ nodes. A generic node $(i,j) \in V$ represent the cell in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of the grid.

There is an edge between vertex $u$ to vertex $v$ iff it is possible to move (in one step) from cell $u$ to cell $v$ without breaking a wall on $v$.
If all directions of movement are allowed this is equivalent to saying that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent and there is no wall on $v$.

Create a directed graph $H$ consisting of $k+1$ copies $G_0, G_1, \dots, G_k$ of $G$.
Intuitively the $i$-th copy represents the situation in which exactly $i$ walls have been broken.

Augment $H$ as follows: for each $i=0, \dots, k-1$ add an edge from vertex $u$ of the $i$-th copy to vertex $v$ of the $(i+1)$-th copy iff it is possible to move (in one step) from cell $u$ to cell $v$ but this requires breaking a wall on $v$.
Again, if all direction of movement are allowed this is equivalent to saying that $u$ and $v$ are adjacent and there is a wall on $v$.

Finally, add a new vertex $t$ and all the edges from vertices $(\ell, \ell)$ in all of the $k+1$ copies of $G$ to $t$.
Notice that the number of vertices is $O(nk)$ and that the number of edges is linear in the number of vertices.

It now suffices to find a shortest path $P = \langle v_0, v_1, \dots, v_h \rangle$ from vertex $(0,0)$ in $G_0$ to $t$.  This can be done in time $O(nk)$ using, e.g., a breadth first search from $(0, 0)$ in $G_0$.
The sought shortest path on the grid has length $h$ and is obtained by traversing the cells corresponding to vertices $v_0$ to $v_{h-1}$.

Comment: This solution is not optimal though

Comment: What do you mean not optimal? Are you referring to the running time or the length of the returned path? I can prove that the length of the returned path is optimal.

Comment: The running time. You can also add a version of any pathfinding algorithm (like Dijkstra's algorithm) to reduce the running time a little bit to $O(n\times min\{k,log(n)\})$

Comment: Although i suppose the running time of $O(nk)$ is enough

Comment: Could you quickly describe how to get a running time of $O(n \log n)$? (for $k=\omega(\log n)$?)

Comment: build a graph where each slot on the grid is a node. connect nodes just as you would have done normally in the grid. for every edge, if it connects a normal cell with a "wall" cell, it will cost $k/2+1$. if the edge connects two walls then $k+1$. other edge will have cost $1$. Now run Dijkstra's algorithm from the top-left to the bottom-right

Comment: sorry, i will edit it in a sec. The weights are not correct as is

Comment: Nice answer! This solution solves, in fact, the more general problem of the shortest at-most-$k$-wall-breaking path in a directed graph with walls.

Answer (score 1):

***Note: This solution assumes you cannot move left or up.***

---

Have you heard about [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)? With a little bit of work, Im pretty sure it can help you find a solution for the question!

An actual solution (using dynamic programming. Please, try to do it yourself first):

let $m$ be the board width (or height). Then $n=m^2$.

Build an empty matrix $M$ of size $m\times m$.

Now, run the following algorithm:

1. For $i$ from $m$ to 1:

   2. For $j$ from $m$ to 1:

      3. Set $M[i,j] = min\{M[i+1,j],M[i,j+1]\} + C$ where $C=k$ if there is a wall and $C=1$ otherwise. (also $M[m+1,j]=0=M[i,m+1]$)

This matrix will contain the costs of the shortest paths between the node $(i,j)$ to the bottom right. To find the actual path, just traverse the lowest valued path between $(0,0)$ and $(m,m)$ in the matrix.

This will cost $O(m^2)=O(n)$